# Customizing ASP.NET Web API Output

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, serialization, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

How can I customize the serialized output of ASP.NET Web API?

Let's say, I want all values in uppercase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have access to the JSON.NET serializer settings. With JSON.NET you can overide conversions using converters e.g. [this datetime one](http://cgeers.com/2011/09/25/writing-a-custom-json-net-datetime-converter/).

You can also implement your own from inheritting from the abstract JsonConverter. See [here](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) for details.

**For your example create the converter:**

```
public class UpperCaseStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return reader.Value.ToString();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var outputValue = value as string;
        writer.WriteValue(outputValue == null ? null : outputValue.ToUpper());
    }
}
```

**And then to register this globally add this config:**

Registration example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856853/webapi-json-net-custom-date-handling)

```
JsonMediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
JsonSerializerSettings jSettings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings();
jSettings.Converters.Add(new UpperCaseStringConverter());
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = jSettings;
```

**To add to a single property on a model just add the annotation:**

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(UpperCaseStringConverter))]
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Kudos to you!