# Asp.net web API datetime format

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a Winform client that sends a json post request to my controller with a datetime value of the format dd/MM/yyyy and the call returns a status code 400.

I tried to add:

```
<globalization uiCulture="fr" culture="fr-FR" />
```

to my web.config file but it's still not working.

Edit:
I should add also That I have no control over the client and that I added:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}")]
```

to my model with no result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are posting this via JSON then you should be able to create a JSON.NET converter for your date format.

In fact in researching this answer I found this full example on SO [WebApi Json.NET custom date handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856853/webapi-json-net-custom-date-handling)

Obviously just alter the conversion in MyDateTimeConvertor to be something that uses the current culture and the format you spefified.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(reader.Value.ToString(), "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

AND

```
writer.WriteValue(((DateTime)value).ToString("dd/mm/yyyy"));
```

Answer (score 11):

There's a pretty simple solution. Just add the CultureInfo to the JsonSerializerSettings in global.asax, method Application_Start().

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = 
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,                           
        DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Unspecified,
        Culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR")
    };
```

Comment: How do you do it in .net core?

Answer (score 1):

before:

```
"AccessStartTime": "2020-12-01T00:00:00",
```

add below code into Application_Start() of Global.asax.cs

```
      IsoDateTimeConverter converter = new IsoDateTimeConverter
        {
            DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal,
            DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        };
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters
         .JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(converter);
```

after:

```
 "AccessStartTime": "2020-12-01 00:00:00",
```

> reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42816827/2736970

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noticed is you have a bug in attribute you specified for your model:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}")]
```

This:

```
{0:dd/mm/yyyy}
```

Is not the same thing as:

```
dd/MM/yyyy
```

mm - for minutes, MM - for months.