# Web-Api datatime serialization issue

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I have some issue with the return of a WEB API.
This API processes the data and returns an object of type `List <Dictionary <string, object >>`.
The problem is that when returning a date (datetime) the return format change depending on the server on which the site is installed.

For example I have these two cases:

[image: Good Format]

[image: Bad Format]

the first is the correct size, while the second is to wrong.

I have the following statement in the code that converts (should convert) the date to the desired format:

```
dict.Add(dc.Caption, ((DateTime)dr[dc.Caption]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

Can you help me?

Bye
Davide

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817108/asp-net-web-api-datetime-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colon (`:`) in a DateTime format string does not always translate to a colon, it stands for "the time separator according to the current culture". See also [MSDN: Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can see this in this code sample, using the Finnish culture, [where the period is used as a time separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Finland):

```
var finnishCulture = new CultureInfo("fi-FI");

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = finnishCulture;

Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"));
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString(@"HH\:mm"));
```

This prints:

```
7.3.2017 15.58.47
15.58
15:58
```

Perhaps let WebAPI do the serialization for you, or if you're sure you want to serialize it yourself, escape the colon: `\:`.