# js can't add timezone offset to '1900-01-01T00:00:00'?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, asp.net-web-api2

I try to `new Date()` to get UTC local time,

but now js can't add timezone offset (eg. add 8 hours for china).

before it works right.

[image]

In the blog [On the nightmare that is JSON Dates. Plus, JSON.NET and ASP.NET Web API](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx)

WebAPI json result with ISO 8601 date format is 

`'2017-05-10T07:50:16'.`

[image]

Comment: Regarding your edit, the ISO 8601 date format used by JSON.NET and Web API includes the added `Z` for UTC. There's an example of this [in JSON.NET's documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm) – `"2012-03-19T07:22Z"`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks, I just found the [`timeago`]( http://timeago.yarp.com/) jquery plugin not work right in chrome 58.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to include timezone information within the string.

For UTC, that can be represented by `Z`.

```
new Date("2017-05-10T07:50:16Z").toUTCString()
// Wed, 10 May 2017 07:50:16 GMT
```

---

The change in behavior reflects a change in the standard.

- [2011, 5th edition](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) (the behavior you're familiar with and expecting)

  > The value of an absent time zone offset is “Z”.
- [2015, 6th edition](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-time-string-format)

  > If the time zone offset is absent, the date-time is interpreted as a local time.
- [2016, 7th edition](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-date-time-string-format) (the current behavior)

  > When the time zone offset is absent, date-only forms are interpreted as a UTC time and **date-time forms are interpreted as a local time**.

Comment: Thanks , maybe that's the webAPI  v2 new  bug.

Answer (score 0):

change the default `DatetimeConverter` :

```
 IsoDateTimeConverter converter = new IsoDateTimeConverter
        {
            DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"
        };

config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(converter);
```

[How to get JSON.NET to serialize date/time to ISO 8601?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42816827/1616023)