# Json.Net, how to serialize DateTimeOffset with 'Z' instead of +00:00, but keep other timezone offsets?

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net

With .NET Core and Json.NET, how can I serialize a `DateTimeOffset` (not `DateTime`) so that the UTC `+00:00` becomes `Z` while keeping any other timezone offset (`-04:00` for example)?

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42816827/918244) is for `DateTime`, but with it, I managed to replace the `+00:00` by `Z` while converting *all* timezones to UTC

```cs
new JsonSerializerSettings {
    Converters = new JsonConverter[] {
        new IsoDateTimeConverter {
            DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal,
            DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'",
        }
    }
};
```

I'd like to retain the timezone offset info, *i.e.*

`2019-12-10T17:00:00Z` for `new DateTimeOffset(2019, 12, 10, 17, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero)`

and

`2019-12-10T13:00:00-04:00` for `new DateTimeOffset(2019, 12, 10, 13, 0, 0, TimeSpan.FromHours(-4))`

The `DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssK"` suggested works for `DateTime` but outputs `+00:00`, not `Z`, for `DateTimeOffset`...

See [this .NET Fiddle for a reproduction](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iduukx) of my attempts.

Comment: I answered your question quickly, but maybe I misunderstood your question.  Is your problem 1) Only applying your converter to `DateTimeOffset`?  2) Getting the correct format for `DateTimeOffset`?

Comment: Getting the correct format for `DateTimeOffset`. i.e. `2019-12-10T17:00:00Z` but `2019-12-10T13:00:00-04:00`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could subclass [`IsoDateTimeConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/IsoDateTimeConverter.cs) and override [`CanConvert`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_DateTimeConverterBase_CanConvert.htm) to only convert objects of type `DateTimeOffset` and `DateTimeOffset?`.  Then, when `DateTimeOffset.Offset` is zero, output as a `DateTime` in universal format:

```
public class IsoDateTimeOffsetConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(DateTimeOffset) || objectType == typeof(DateTimeOffset?);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dateTimeOffset = (DateTimeOffset)value;
        if (dateTimeOffset.Offset == TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            // If there is no offset, serialize as a DateTime
            base.WriteJson(writer, dateTimeOffset.UtcDateTime, serializer);
        }
        else
        {
            base.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
        }
    }       
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
    Converters = {
        new IsoDateTimeOffsetConverter(),
    }
};
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dbsGIR).