# c# - Get Datetime local format

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

When I post a datetime value to my web API I get different results
and I want to get datetime in local format

**MyViewModel :**

```cs
public class MyViewModel 
{
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

I post json like this

```
{ "Time": "2020-09-08T04:00:00.000Z" }
```

to api/Values

```cs
[RoutePrefix("api/Values")]
public class ValuesController: ApiController 
{
    // POST api/values
    public object Post(MyViewModel model) 
    {
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
    }
}
```

the result in the same format is UTC

```
{\"Time\": \"2020-09-08T04:00:00Z\"}
```

---

But when I post the same Json to HomeController

```cs
public class HomeController: Controller 
{
    public object Post(MyViewModel model) 
    {
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
    }
}
```

the result is in local format like this

```
{ "Time":"2020-09-08T07:00:00+03:00" }
```

I want result to be in local format like HomeController

How can i implement it ?

Comment: I tried to fix time by model.Time.ToLocalTime(); but I want this for any datetime in my webapi

Comment: Do the answers here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811410/how-to-get-json-net-to-serialize-date-time-to-iso-8601

Comment: What do you expect it to look like? It's a c# string.. it will be escaped. Do this and then view the file: `File.WriteAllText(@"c:\test.json", Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model))`

Comment: Your HomeController and ValuesController inherit from different controlle types. They probably have different serialization settings

Comment: how can I set the setting of serialization to both controller apicontroler and controller @SimonC