# Force Framework to use Enum Entity Name instead of its Value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I created a ASP.NET MVC 4 Web application. Within this application i implemented several rest webservices and here comes my question: Is it possible to force the object serialization to use the enum entity names instead of their values?

This is my enum:

```
    public enum ReturnCode { OK, InvalidParameter }
```

This is what I get:

```
{
   "returnCode": 0,
   "data": null
}
```

But this is what I want:

```
{
   "returnCode": OK,
   "data": null
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Just add another property that returns the string version of the enum.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/json-serialization-of-c-sharp-enum-as-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a JsonConverter.

There is a native one for JSON.Net [`StringEnumConverter`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter.htm) mentioned in this question [JSON serialization of enum as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/json-serialization-of-c-sharp-enum-as-string)

Either anotate your property:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum ReturnCode { OK, InvalidParameter }
```

Or use the config examples in [WebApi Json.NET custom date handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856853/webapi-json-net-custom-date-handling) to register in the global serialiser settings.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to make a suggestion without better understanding of your usage patterns...but none the less.

Make the enum a private field.

Built a public string property with a getter which returns the entity name of the private enum field and a setter which uses Enum.Parse to set the private field value

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. You need to declare additional string property and use it when serializing/deserializing.

Example:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyResource
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Data { get; set; }

    public ReturnCode Code { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "returnCode")]
    string ReturnCodeString
    {
        get { return this.Code.ToString(); }
        set
        {
            ReturnCode r;
            this.Code = Enum.TryParse(value, true, out r) ? r : ReturnCode.OK;
        }
    }
}
```

So now you can pass the value of enum as a string (in both direction from server and from client) i.e.:

```
{
   "returnCode": "OK",
   "data": null
}
```

or

```
{
   "returnCode": "InvalidParameter",
   "data": null
}
```